# Graphics are NaN whereas no heartbeat was received: what could explain this?

Tags: monitoring, ganglia

I use [ganglia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganglia_(software)) to monitor my computer cluster. On Ganglia Web Interface, I sometimes have the following issue: given a node, according to the physical view and the node view, the node has sent a heartbeat recently, while in the host view all graphics are nan. What could explain this?

(`gmond` has been running for a while on each node, so the issue is not that there isn't enough heartbeats to plot)

Host view:

[image]

Node view:

[image]